# Change Data Capture in Pentaho Community Edition 8.3 Version

Tags: mysql, oracle, pentaho

I am trying to do CDC on pentaho 8.3 version Community edition, Source is Oracle and the target is Mysql.
The date format in Oracle is in the format DD-MON-YY (01-JAN-19), but when I see the data in PDI(Preview)
it appears as `2019/01/01 00:00:00.00000000`.

Source query:

```
Select ColA, ColB 
from table
where Last_upd_dt > ? and last_upd_dt <=?
```

in the table input step and getting the start_date and end_date from the Get System info step (Start_date as start date range, end_date as end date range) and in the Transformation Properties >> Logging>> Transformation gave a Log_table along with connections. But when I execute the transformation I am getting below errors:

> Error: Unable to write the log record to log table[Log]
>
> Error: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
>          Error inserting/updating row
>   Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1900-01-01 03:00:00.0' for Column Start_date' at row 1
>   Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.execeptions.MysqlDataTruncation:Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1900-01-01 03:00:00.0' for Column Start_date' at row 1

Answer (score 1):

That's because date time format problem.Place **select value** between input and output and define **date format  dd-MMM-yyyy**  or which is supported by **output step** in meta-data tab.

Comment: There is no OUTPUT step involved, As the data is being read and the filter conditions are applied at the INPUT step (Select ColA, ColB from table where Last_upd_dt > ? and last_upd_dt <=?). How can I use select value step

Comment: you can use before input step where **?** is coming from previous step right?